# Locating all elements between starting and ending points, given by value (not index)

Tags: language-agnostic

The problem is as follows,

I would be given a set of x and y coordinates(an coordinate array of around 30 to 40 thousand) of a long rope. The rope is lying on the ground and can be in any shape.

Now I would be given a start point(essentially x and y coordinate) and an ending point.

What is the efficient way to determine the set of x and y coordinates from the above mentioned coordinate array lie between the start and end points.

Exhaustive searching ie looping 40k times is not an acceptable solution (mentioned on the question paper)

A little bit margin for error is acceptable

Comment: Is the "coordinate array" two-dimensional, i.e. a matrix?  Or is it a one-dimensional array that stores coordinate locations?

Comment: Define "between the start and end points".  Does that mean the coordinates where the rope intersects a straight line between the start and end points, or all points on the rope between the start and end points?

Comment: @Demian Brecht. Thats where it gets tricky the rope is not assumed to be linear ..... it is be like a uturn on the road and looping 40k times is not considered to be a efficient solution

Comment: @Andrew the points that are in the coordinate array that I mentioned in the start of the question and lie between the start and end points, not a straight line between them ... if it were a straight line it would have been a simple problem.... hope i convey myself

Comment: @Maxpm It doesnt matter really, but, yes I would imagine it as a two dimensional array

Comment: @Nick: Why is a loop which iterates 40k times not efficient? It's O(n). I can't imagine an algorithm of a better complexity, you have to look at every coordinate at least once.

Comment: @Christian Ammer that was mentioned in the question ... I think everyone can come up with that solution ... probably that is why the examiners put this clause in the question ... I mean that would be a case of exhaustive searching and would not scale if the rope was considered to be of infinite length ..... I do not know the exact reason but this was the question .... I would go ahead and add that to the question thanks for notifying....

Comment: @Nick: Ok, but think about it: you can't ignore any of the points. Approximating a rope by just looking at every fifth coordinate (for example) doesn't bring you closer to the solution because nothing is said about the minimal and maximal distance between two coordinates. Already the next coordinate after a visited (noticed) coordinate could bring you far away from the start point or the end point.

Comment: If the set of coordinates is not sorted i think the best solution MUST be at least O(n). You cannot discard an coordinate be your own, só you have to check all

Comment: @Christian Ammer that what i am stuck at how to determine a subset that would provide the required solution

Comment: @Plínio Pantaleão the set of coordinates (coordinate array) is sorted in a sense that is it contains all the points in order

Comment: can you give example input and output?  I'm having a really hard time understanding this question.

Comment: @koool: How often will you change (add/delete tricky) the title of your question?

Comment: jus doing it because I want answer to this question badly ... sorry if it bothers you ... I just want someone to help me on this ... sorry again

Answer (score 4):

We need to find the start point in the array, then the end point.  For each, we can think of the rope as describing a function of distance from that point, and we're looking for the lowest point on that distance graph.  If one point is a long way away and another is pretty close, we can do some kind of interpolation guess of where to search next.

```
distance
    |  /---\
    |--     \  /\       -
    |        --  ------- --   ------     ----------    -
    |                      \ /      \---/          \--/
    +-----------------------X--------------------------- array index
```

In the representation above, we want to find "X"... we look at the distances at a few points, get an impression of the slope of the distance curve, possibly even the rate of change of that slope, to help guide our next bit of probing....

To refine the basic approach of doing binary- or interpolated- searches in areas where we know the distance values are low, we may be able to use the following:

- if we happen to be given the rope length and know the coordinate samples are equidistant along the rope, then we can calculate a maximum change in distance from our target point per sample.
- if we know the rope has a stiffness ensuring it can't loop in a trivially small diameter, then

  - there's a known limit to how fast the slope of the curve can change
  - distance curve converges to vertical on both sides of the 0 point
- you could potentially cross-reference/combine distance with, or use instead, the direction of each point from the target: only at the target would the direction instantly change ~180 degrees (how well the data points capture this still depends on the distance between adjacent samples and any stiffness of the rope).

Otherwise, there's always risk the target point may weirdly be encased by two very distance points, frustrating our whole searching algorithm (that must be what they mean about some margin for error - every now and then this search would have to revert to a O(N) brute-force search because any trend analysis fails).

Comment: Hill-climbing. As you note, requires the additional constraint that adjacent points are not distant. Note also that there can be multiple local maxima -- e.g., a simple coil of rope.

Comment: 1. rope length unknown
2. points aren't equidistant
 and yes I think the problem of local maxima would negatively affect this

Comment: @koool: those issues remove some optimisation possibility in applying this approach, but don't undermine its fundamental potential.  It's a probabilistic approach: it may be better or worse than a linear search depending on the data set and start/end points, but on average is likely to be better....

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time search, sometimes linear traversal is the simplest, fastest solution. Maybe that's the case for this problem.

Iterate through the ordered list of points until finding the start or end, and then collect points until hitting the other endpoint.

Now, if we expected to repeat the search, we could build an index to the points.

**Edit:** This presumes no additional constraints beyond those mentioned by @koool. Constraining the distance between the points would allow the hill-climbing approach described in @Tony's answer.

Comment: That would be a case of exhaustive searching which is not acceptable according to the problem....I have edited the question ... I forgot to mention that the first time.... sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: Have you ever heard of the Kobayashi Maru?

Comment: @Andy Thomas-Cramer nope what is that

Comment: It's an intentionally no-win test given to observe behavior, in the fictional Star Trek universe. Some interview questions are given to see how you think and how you interact. Will you see the simple solution? How do you behave while the interviewer plays devil's advocate?

Comment: maybe but I think there is a solution because the interviewer mentioned that this is the most common problem for dynamic path determination or something like that.

Comment: @Nick, given an array with completely random contents, what's the most efficient way to find two values in this array?

Comment: the array here is not completely random ... the coordinate array is in order

Comment: @Nick, by "in order," do you mean that the points in the array are ordered the same as they occur along the string? Because then I'm going to ask you to imagine that the random values in the array are linked by a string invisible to the algorithm ...

Comment: yes in order means  that the points in the array are ordered the same as they occur along the rope...though i dont quite get ur second question

Comment: @koool - I have an array of random points. The most efficient algorithm to find a particular point is O(n), right? Now, imagine a rope that lays over those points, in order (there are infinitely many rope shapes to pick from). Does the complexity change? No, simply imagining a rope does not change the complexity. The algorithm needs additional data or constraints to improve efficiency -- like those suggested by @Tony above. In an interview, asking additional questions about requirements is a good sign; I usually leave the requirements incomplete to see if the candidate will ask.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve it accurately using anything other than exhaustive search. Say for cases where the rope is folded into half and the resulting double rope forms a spiral with the two ends on the centre.

However if we assume that long portions of the rope are in straight line, then we can eliminate a lot of points based on the slope check:

```
if (abs(slope(x[i],y[i],x[i+1],y[i+1])
        -slope(x[i+1],y[i+1],x[i+2],y[i+2]))<tolerance)
    eliminate (x[i+1],y[i+1]);
```

This will reduce the search time significantly if large portions of the rope are in straight line. But will be linear WRT number of remaining points.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you've got a sorted list of the points that comprise the entire rope and you're given two arbitrary points from within that list, and tasked with returning the sublist that exists between those two points.

I'm going to make the assumption that the start and end points that are provided are guaranteed to coincide exactly with points within the sorted list (otherwise it introduces a host of issues, particularly if the rope may be arbitrarily thin and passes by the start/end points multiple times).

That means all you're really looking for are the indices of the two provided coordinates.  Or the index of one, and the answer to "is the second coordinate to the right or to the left?".

A simple O(n) solution to that would be:

```
For each index in array
    coord = array[index]
    if (coord == point1)
        startIndex = index
    if (coord == point2) 
        endIndex = index

if (endIndex < startIndex)
    swap(startIndex, endIndex)

return array.sublist(startIndex, endIndex)
```

Or, if you wanted to optimize for repeated queries, I'd suggest a hashing based approach where you map each cooordinate to its index in the array.  Something like:

```
//build the map (do this once, at init)
map = {}
For each index in array
    coord = array[index]
    map[coord] = index

//find a sublist (do this for each set of start/end points)
startIndex = map[point1]
endIndex = map[point2]

if (endIndex < startIndex)
    swap(startIndex, endIndex)

return array.sublist(startIndex, endIndex)
```

That's O(n) to build the map, but once it's built you can determine the sublist between any two points in O(1).  Assuming an efficient hashmap, of course.

Note that if my assumption doesn't hold, then the same solutions are still usable, provided that as a first step you take the provided start and end points and locate the points in the array that best correspond to each one.  As noted, unless you are given some constraints regarding the thickness of the rope then interpolating from an arbitrary coordinate to one that's actually part of the rope can only be guesswork at best.